# How do I prevent winamp from autoplaying a cd when I put it into the drive

Tags: windows-vista, winamp

I use Winamp to listen to music and are currently in the process of ripping some cds. Regretfully every time I put a cd in the drive, winamp stops playing the music I am currently listening to and starts playing the cd.

Anybody know how to stop this? Even terminating winamp doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Control Panel > Autoplay > and set the audio CD's to Ask Me Every time, or to Take no action. This way, you have control over what the CD's do and you have the option to import the music or play it with something else.